# Java Array loop error

Tags: arrays, json

I am working with Orchestration Design, but found that it doesn't have all the functions I need, so we have a lot of hard coded JAVA.

I have read several post discussing similar errors as below.

> org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["customer"] not
>   found

I have tried several of the solutions that were previously published, but am still not able to get this fixed.  I have only 2 weeks of java training, and next to no real world experience with Java.  So if you can break it down or provide more guidance I would be really appreciative.
Here is my data:

```
{"statusCode":"200",
"statusMessage":"OK",
"data":
    {"customer":
        [{"name":"John  Smith",
        "dob":"06-14-2000",
        "phones":
            [{"phoneID":"d3dd30b1-cd47-46f5-8e06-1fd5e8631203",
            "phoneNumberTypeCode":"3",
            "phoneNumber":"2162100834",
            "sortOrderCode":"1"},

            {"phoneID":"0153632c-ae8f-4b12-a68f-1ab33fa4e7e3",
            "phoneNumberTypeCode":"3",
            "phoneNumber":"3306973358",
            "sortOrderCode":"2"}]},

        {"name":"same  five",
        "dob":"06-01-1968",
        "phones":
            [{"phoneID":"83c49dd0-d308-4e88-b25e-4ddff53bf124",
            "phoneNumberTypeCode":"3",
            "phoneNumber":"3306973358",
            "sortOrderCode":"1"}]},

        {"name":"same  five",
        "dob":"06-01-1968",
        "phones":
            [{"phoneID":"ac61e9ce-ea4e-46c3-85d7-cd07bdcbf54e",
            "phoneNumberTypeCode":"3",
            "phoneNumber":"3306973358",
            "sortOrderCode":"1"}]},

        {"name":"kjhdv  askljdh",
        "dob":"06-01-1968",
        "phones":
            [{"phoneID":"8706e547-c9fe-4844-84a8-f4c78abd7277",
            "phoneNumberTypeCode":"3",
            "phoneNumber":"3306973358",
            "sortOrderCode":"1"}]}]}}
```

At this point I am only interested in getting to the DOB.  I need to compare it to data entered by a customer to try pull the correct account.  Later on I will need to get to the rest of the data, but I hope once I understand how to get to the DOB I can figure the rest out on my own.

Here is the code I have been writing.  I have a lot of commented out code which was examples I found on this forum and tried to get to work as well.  Each version give me an error

> JSONObject["customer"] not found.

I do realize that there are other posts with this same issue, but I have not been able to make any of the solutions work for me (probably due to my lack of experience)

```
public String getAccount(String requestUrl, String token) throws Exception {

    String statusmessage = "";

    try {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(requestUrl);

        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
        getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", token);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("StatCode = "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            return "500";
            //throw new Exception("Failed : HTTP error code : " +
            //response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println("RESPONSE *** " + responseStr);
        String jsonResp = responseStr;
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResp);
        statusmessage = jsonObj.get("statusMessage").toString();
        System.out.println("StatusMes : " + statusmessage);
        String data = jsonObj.get("data").toString();
        System.out.println("Data : " + data);
        //String customer = jsonObj.get("customer").toString();

        JSONArray customer = jsonObj.getJSONArray("customer");
        for(int i=0;i<customer.length();i++)
        {
        JSONObject jb1 = customer.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jb1.getString("name");
        }

        //JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
           // JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("Message");
           // for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            //    JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //}
                //TopTenGetterSetter obj = new TopTenGetterSetter();  

        /* JSONArray Customer = jsonObj.getJSONArray("customer");
        String customer = Customer.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
        for (int i = 0; i < Customer.length(); i++) {
            String name = Customer.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            System.out.println(name);
            String dob = Customer.getJSONObject(i).getString("dob");
            System.out.println(dob);
            String phones = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getString("phones");
            System.out.println(phones);
            String Position = Liste.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Position").toString();
            System.out.println(Position);
         */             

        //JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(jsonResp);
        //JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("JObjects");
        //JSONArray jsonArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("JArray1");
        //for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++) {
        //  JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // "...and get their component and their value."
            //String[] elementNames = JSONObject.class.getName(objectInArray);
            //for (String elementName : elementNames) {
            //  String value = objectInArray.getString(elementName);
            //}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this :)

```
   JSONObject mainNode =  new JSONObject(jsonResp);
   JSONObject dataNode =  mainNode.getJSONObject("data");
   JSONArray customerNode = dataNode.getJSONArray("customer");
   for(int i=0;i<customerNode.length();i++)
   {
        JSONObject childNode = customerNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = childNode.getString("name").toString();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

JSONObject["customer"] not found because it doesn't exists. On your JSON the "customer" is under "data" not under root.